# Mapbox - mapbox-gl-compare options

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Does the mapbox-gl-compare plugin have any options for controlling the initial position of div.mapboxgl-compare? By default it is a split view 50/50. But I would like it load full position to the left? Hiding the second map.

Or does someone know to approach this?

[GitHub - mapbox-gl-compare](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-compare)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the source, `function o(t, e, n) { }` (which initialises the plugin) contains the following setting: `this._setPosition(this._bounds.width / 2)`.

You'll be able to edit this to fit your needs.